# Why is my border top color not showing after I had use the right border syntax

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to apply a colour to the the border top of my div but it isn't working out.
I've use the right border syntax.
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top-color: red;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a minimal reproduction code with your HTML and CSS so that we can help you figuring what isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<style>
.div1{border: 1px solid black;
border-top-color: red
}
</style>
<div class="div1">Just test</div>
<br><br>
<div style="border: 1px solid black;border-top-color: red">Just test</div>
```

I've given you two ways solve your problem

```
<style>
.div1{border: 1px solid black;
border-top-color: red
}
</style>
<div class="div1">Just test</div>
```

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;border-top-color: red">Just test</div>
```